Ideal number of randomized concordancing lines
I want to perform randomized concordancing on a news corpus with 807 mil. tokens from 2 mil. documents from 2011-2022. Is there any ideal number of concordancing in order to be able to make a generalization of the node I select?
I specifically want to perform a concordancing on the lemma "gay", and I want to make a generalized statements about how the gays are represented in the corpus (therefore also performing a critical discourse analysis [CDA]).
Most studies I have read have used the 10 lines randomized concordancing (Horst, 2005; Jaworska, 2017), but these studies are mostly language-learning related. Another studies on corpus-based CDA uses different of number of concordancing lines, ranging from 5-35 (Freake & Mary, 2011; Jaworska, 2016; Kim, 2014).
Will 10 concordancing lines be enough? Of course the more lines the better, but the more lines will contribute more to the wordcount of my document, and I believe it would be best to spare the wordcount for the actual analysis and interpretation (using CDA).
References:

Freake, R., & Mary, Q. (2012). A cross-linguistic corpus-assisted discourse study of language ideologies in Canadian newspapers. In Proceedings of the 2011 Corpus Linguistics Conference (pp. 1-11).

Horst, M., Cobb, T., & Nicolae, I. (2005). Expanding academic vocabulary with an interactive on-line database.

Jaworska, S. (2016). A comparative corpus-assisted discourse study of the representations of hosts in promotional tourism discourse. Corpora, 11(1), 83-111.

Jaworska, S. (2017). 24 Corpora and corpus linguistic approaches to studying business language. Handbooks of Applied Linguistics, 583.

Kim, K. H. (2014). Examining US news media discourses about North Korea: A corpus-based critical discourse analysis. Discourse & Society, 25(2), 221-244.



Obviously, the more you have statistically, the better. However, you have to define what you mean by gay. There are many dependent variables here.

Hi @Lambie, thanks for the input. What I meant by "gay" is the gay people, who are part of the LGBT community.

I just meant you have to define your search terms. Beyond that, the more the merrier. BUT just the presence of the word will not tell anyone anything much. You need to sort out collocations.

Yes, I also aim to run a collocational analysis @Lambie. I am particularly trying to find out the linguistics strategies employed in representing gays in the corpus (hence the CDA after the CL)

The answer is "it depends".
First, there is the word itself. A polysemous word might require more lines, as you have more meanings to deal with. The word gay has at least two meanings, but I assume in news data one will be more common.
Also, the overall frequency of the word is relevant. This is somewhat related to the first point, as common words tend to have more distinct usages (and thus more meanings, if we assume that usages equal meanings). For rare words you will find that fewer lines capture more of the usages, whereas for common words ten lines will barely give you any insights.
Given that there is no fixed number of lines to use, I would be pragmatic: Look through a set of, say 10, lines and develop your description/statement. Then continue looking through more lines, and see if the new occurrences affect your statement, or whether they confirm it. If you have looked at a number of additional lines without gaining any further insights, then you could argue that your statement seems valid.
This of course presupposes a definition of "affect"; you might decide that a line only slightly changes your statement, but not enough to actually be useful.
The problem is (at least it was when I still worked in corpus analysis, and I don't think it has been solved since) that there are no hard and fast guidelines for how much data you need to look at. Much of text and corpus analysis is still exploratory, and methodologies are not fixed; everyone has their own way of doing things and recommends that, but there is no objective way of resolving such issues for now.
Also, I am surprised that concordance lines contribute to word count. If this is a problem, then just put them in an appendix.

Thanks for the input! I find it very helpful :) Yeah it contributes to wordcount, since I write it as a table, however I might be able to just turn the tables into png. My supervisor recommended me to not changed it into png however
